# static graphs v.s. dynamic graphs

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

> In summary, static graphs are easy to optimize but lack the expressivity found in higher-level languages; dynamic graphs provide this missing expressivity but introduce new compilation and execution challenges, especially on heterogeneous hardware and FPGAs.

from

> Roesch, Jared, Steven Lyubomirsky, Logan Weber, Josh Pollock, Marisa Kirisame, Tianqi Chen, and Zachary Tatlock. "Relay: a new IR for machine learning frameworks." In Proceedings of the 2nd ACM SIGPLAN International Workshop on Machine Learning and Programming Languages, pp. 58-68. ACM, 2018.

My question is

- Why are static graphs easier to optimize than dynamic graphs?
- Why are static graphs less expressive than dynamic graphs?
- What compilation and execution challenge dynamic graphs face? How about static graphs? What causes these problems for dynamic graphs?

If such a question is not suitable to be asked here, please redirect me to another stack. Thanks!

Comment: I have posted a somewhat related question (with bounty!) here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382260/temporal-generalization-of-graphs-density-vs-n-and-m